# How can I use a binary image to mask augmented reality with OpenGL and ARcore?

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

I need to render only some part of virtual object like in this image where part of Android Robot is hidden [image]

For doing this I use "Stencil Testing" and i draw with OpenGL a simple rectangle. 
The problem is that now I need the part "hidden" to be not static but dynamic and I have to choose the part to hidden from a binary image like this one [image] where the black part needs to "hide" (like in the example before) the virtual object and virtual plane. The "mask" will be changed for every frame.

Comment: Any help? i'm pretty stuck...

Comment: How to achive this type of mask using arcore and stencil buffer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118280/problem-using-stencil-mask-on-3d-object-in-arcore